# Error while fitting model after One Hot Encoding

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am using one hot encoding(I am aware ordinal encoding is better in this case) for categorical variables of Titanic dataset. The one hot encoding is successfully done. However, the model fitting throws the following error:

**ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.**

Here is the code I am running:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
def one_hot_encode_features(df_train,df_test):
    features = ['Fare', 'Cabin', 'Age', 'Sex']
    #features = [ 'Cabin', 'Sex']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])
    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        integer_encoding_train=le.transform(df_train[feature])
        integer_encoding_test=le.transform(df_test[feature])
        integer_encoding_train = integer_encoding_train.reshape(len(integer_encoding_train), 1)
        integer_encoding_test = integer_encoding_test.reshape(len(integer_encoding_test), 1)
        df_train[feature] = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoding_train)

        df_test[feature] = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoding_test)

    return df_train, df_test
data_train, data_test = one_hot_encode_features(data_train, data_test)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = data_train.drop(['Survived', 'PassengerId'], axis=1)
Y = data_train['Survived']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=23)
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    clf = GaussianNB()
    acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

The error is removed if I use ordinal encoding instead of One Hot. I am new to handling category variables so cannot figure out the error.

Comment: OneHotEncoder will return a 2-d array which you are storing in a single column in pandas. This will not be handled correctly by scikit. You need to make a simple 2-d array (without the nesting as you are doing now).]

Comment: On top of that OneHotEncoder will return a sparse matrix, which pandas think as a single element, and will populate the whole column with the copies of that "single element".

Comment: Correct Vivek, I see the copies when exported to csv! How to get a simple 2d one hot encoded array? Thanks.

Comment: @VivekKumar: Should I use sparse=False to avoid sparse matrix.

Comment: Even in that case, `df_train[feature]` will be filled only by the first column of output from OneHotEncoder, not all. You need to concatenate the resultant data and then put into dataframe

Comment: The array can be appended to a column of a dataframe correctly by:
        df_train[feature] = list(onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoding_train).toarray()).
However, next step is to convert  object datatype in training algo, which I am use it in training.

Comment: Yes, but thats again a nesting. You are filling a multi-dimension array into a single dimension column of pandas. Scikit wont handle that.